# where do I find ubuntu 10.04 setup files

Tags: 10.04

I need to install ubuntu 10.04. My CPU is i5 and my current ubuntu is 14.04. How can I find setup files?

Comment: 10.04 is off topic as far as it a desktop concerns. All official releases can be found on http://releases.ubuntu.com/ 10.04 server version can be found on: http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the previous version you request with this link, but I'm sincerely curious, bordering on doubtful, about your reason to install it.  Can you tell us why it is you "need" to install it, so maybe we can help you with a better solution?

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Comment: My specific software doesn't work on 14.04, that's why I need to 10.04

Comment: I confess, that's a good reason if I ever heard one, and deeply disturbing at the same time.  Here I've been making games from the 1980s written for DOS run under Ubuntu, and you are telling me that there's linux software that ran on a version of Ubuntu that is now only 4 years old which will not run under the current flavor of Ubuntu?  Please tell me the name of this software?

Comment: @gyropyge something depending on gconf ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for liking my previous answer which I admit, strictly speaking, answered your question.  However now that you have fleshed out your need in comments, I have what may be better suggestions.

I've only just googled "gconf" just enough to know that I don't know what you are getting at, but I still may have an idea which may be of help to you...  I was going to suggest you move sideways to an alternate Ubuntu derivative such as LUBUNTU which might still use gconf, but then I did some digging and found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226493&s=9ec7188bbbd81c88d51f1de521ec26fc&p=13035130#post13035130), "*Install the dconf-editor instead*".  Is that useful?